# How to to compare two points in 2d space

Tags: c++, stdset

I have a class for holding my `Points` in 2D space like this:

```
class Point{
public:
Point(double a, double b){ x = a; y = b; }

//some additional information

private:
    double x, y;
};
```

I like to have these `Points` in a `std::set` but I dont know how to write the compare struct

```
struct cCompare{
    bool operator()(const Point &p1, const Point &p2){
         //what should I write here??
    }
};
```

Two Points like `p` and `q` are equal if `(p_1,p_2) = (q_1,q_2)`. Do I have to store some additional information in my `Point` class? Something like index or any unique number for each `Point`? And have something like this:

```
struct cCompare{
    bool operator()(const Point &p1, const Point &p2){
         return (p1.index < p2.index);
    }
};
```

Comment: Why not providing `bool Point::operator<(const Point& other)` in 1st place?

Comment: You may use: `return std::tie(p1.x, p1.y) < std::tie(p2.x, p2.y);`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why shouldn't I use this way?(the struct way)

Comment: @MoNo 1. It's idiomatic 2. `p1 < p2` is more natural, no?

Comment: @MoNo Well, the point of classes is to encapsulate the data and operations applied to them, isn't it?

Comment: As the order relationship between Point is not natural/intuitive, I would say that having the order outside of Point is not bad.

Comment: Why would you want to store data that cannot be naturally sorted in a sorted container in first place? Won't `std::vector` do the trick?

Comment: @Drop Im trying to implement an algorithm, and in that algorithm its said that I should use a red black tree for holding my data in order to find and delete elements faster, so I used std::set.

Comment: @MoNo: if the order has no meaning to the algorithm, and all you need is a collection that can insert, remove and find particular values, then you'd probably be better off with `unordered_set`, and implement a hash instead of a comparator. Perhaps the advice was written before that was added to the standard.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks for your advice, My algorithm says that I should be able to find any elements in O(lgn), A red-black tree can do this for me, Why do you suggest that I should use `unordered_set`? is it faster?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes you are right, I also need to sort my `Points` based on their distance from some other points. so I need to write maybe more than 3 or 4 compare structs.

Comment: I would recommend a spatial index for this. It will have superior performance.

Comment: @MoNo: with certain caveats, `unordered_set` has constant-time lookup and amortised constant-time insert, and typically both are faster than a R-B tree. The caveats are that there exist bad worst cases where all your data collides on the same hash value, and everything becomes linear. So the data structure to use might depend whether you're after best worst-case complexity or best practical performance.

Answer (score 7):

If you need just any ordering relation for the sake of storing in a set, you could use the dictionary order:

`P1 < P2` iff `P1.x < P2.x || (P1.x == P2.x && P1.y < P2.y)`